# Word for aliasing globals or properties as local variables for better compression

Tags: javascript, variables, build, compression, minify

For the last few weeks, I've had a maddening case of "tip-of-the-tongue" syndrome concerning a colloquial verb I read a while ago while digging through uncompressed JavaScript.

At the top of the module's closure, the author had assigned commonly used values like true to a JavaScript variable named "TRUE", false to a variable named "FALSE", and similar transformations applied to other suspects. In a comment, the author had written something along the lines of "Here we'll ******* some commonly used variables for better minification". I vaguely remember it sounding something like, uhm... "kludge" or something like that...? Was ages ago.

Either way, I see this practice all the time with scripts the size of Olympus Mons, I just wish I remembered the damn word... :(

**EDIT:** Yeah, okay, it definitely wasn't "kludge", but I vaguely remember it having a similar phonetic structure.

This is starting to keep me up at night...

Comment: "mirror"? Kludge is usually reserved for a bad practice but something considered necessary to get something working the way you want. Like C++ is a kludge for C programmers who want to do OO but don't want to learn Java (pax ducks for cover).

Comment: Probably it was "purge"?

Comment: No no, it was a made-up sounding word. Definitely not in your standard dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

***GOT IT!!!!*** I knew it ended in a "-ge"...

The word is [munge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mung_%28computer_term%29).

> The term was coined in 1958 in the Tech Model Railroad Club at the
>   Massachusetts Institute of Technology. In 1960 the backronym "Mash
>   Until No Good" was created to describe Mung, and a while after it was
>   revised to "Mung Until No Good", making it one of the first recursive
>   acronyms. It lived on as a recursive command in the editing language
>   TECO.

BRB, getting that tattooed somewhere accessible.